# Way to know what objects a python multiprocessing manager is sharing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In python multiprocessing module, in order to obtain an object from a remote Manager, most recipes tell us that we need to build a getter to recover each object:

```
class QueueMgr(multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager): pass
datos=Queue()
resultados=Queue()
topList=list(top)
QueueMgr.register('get_datos',callable=lambda:datos)
QueueMgr.register('get_resultados',callable=lambda:resultados)
QueueMgr.register('get_top',callable=lambda:topList)
def Cola_run():
    queueMgr=QueueMgr(address=('172.2.0.1', 25555),authkey="foo")
    queueMgr.get_server().serve_forever()
Cola=Thread(target=Cola_run)
Cola.daemon=True
Cola.start()
```

and than the same getter must be declared in the client program:

```
class QueueMgr(multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager): pass
QueueMgr.register('get_datos')
QueueMgr.register('get_resultados')
QueueMgr.register('get_top')
queueMgr=QueueMgr(address=('172.22.0.4', 25555),authkey="foo")
queueMgr.connect()
datos=queueMgr.get_datos()
resultados=queueMgr.get_resultados()
top=queueMgr.get_top()._getvalue()
```

Ok, it covers most usage cases. But I find the code looks ugly. Perhaps I am not getting the right recipe. But if it is really so, then at least I could do some nicer code in the client, perhaps automagically declaring the getters, if I were able to known in advance what objects the Manager is sharing. Is they a way to do it?

It is particularly troubling if you think that the instances of SyncManager provided by multiprocessing.Manager() allow to create sophisticated Proxy objects but that any client connecting to such SyncManager seems to need to obtain the reference to such proxies from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from introspecting into the class and, for each shared attribute, generating the getter and calling `register`.

Comment: I see. Is there some standard recipe for it? Still, I am not sure if it is going to work too for the instances generated by multiprocessing.Manager(), will it?